# Debugging Console in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, console

So I wrote this code but when I try to run it as a Java application, the console doesn't show anything but terminated. I tried to debug console by going at Preferences-Run/Debug-Console to show when the program writes to standard out or when the program writes to standard error but it didn't work either. This is my code and thanks in advance for your help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Frame4 extends JFrame implements UpdatableView {
    private Counter count;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Number = 0");
    private JPanel drawing;
    public Frame4(Counter c, JPanel panel) {
        count = c;
        drawing = panel;
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(label);
        cp.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        cp.add(drawing, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p2.add(new CountButton("Count", count, this)
        setTitle("Frame 4");
        setSize(200, 180);
        setVisible(true);
        }
        public void update() {
            label.setText("Number = " + count.countOf());
            drawing.repaint();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {}
    }
```

Comment: Eh, you have nothing in your `main` method...

Comment: -1. Next time, show some effort and format the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `main` method is empty. put the creation a frameobject in it:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Counter c = new Counter();
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  new Frame4(c, panel);
}
```

Comment: I tried that and this is what is shown in the console: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at Frame4.main(Frame4.java:27)

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` method does not do anything.

Hence no output